# Открыть стандартный браузер с конкретной web-страницей

Tags: c#, браузер

Как через `С#` открыть бразуер с конкретным адресом? Ну или новую вкладку в браузере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

Comment: о, спасибо!
а как управлять вкладками, которые я открыл через программу? 
то есть например когда я открываю новую вкладку посредством своей прогаммы, я хочу закрыть сначала предыдущую, не трогая при этом те, которые были открыты вручную

Comment: Если ответ Вас утраивает, примите его пожалуйста, дабы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: ответ, в принципе, устраивает, да) но появился вытекающий из него, который я описал в комментарии выше

Comment: @jackair: Это уже другой вопрос, ответ на него — в общем случае никак, для конкретных браузеров по-разному.

Comment: Думаю об этом не стоит особо беспокоиться, тестировал сейчас с IE, - если уже есть открытое окно, то открывается новая вкладка. Думаю в остальных браузерах будет аналогично.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет вкладок:

```
//отфильтруем процессы в системе - интересны только браузеры (в данном случае IE)
var ieProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().ToList()
                         .Where(x => x.ProcessName.Equals("IExplore"));

//делаем что-то с вкладками браузера
//например, закрываем:
foreach(Process proc in ieProcesses)
{
    proc.Kill();
}
```

Соответственно, если нужны юругие браузеры, расширяем условия фильтрации.

Код не тестил, но суть такая.

Comment: Ну вы уж прямо так кровожадно, `proc.Kill()`. А вдруг юзер листал себе новости в соседней вкладке? (Да, я тоже не люблю IE, так что `Kill` не считаю сильно уж необоснованным.)

Comment: @VladD, это уже вопрос фильтрации. тогда нужно проверять атрибуты процесса...не помню , честно говоря, как :) атрибуты процесса можно вытащить с использованием WMI, но это уже отдельная задача.

Comment: @Макс Жуков: а если одно окно содержит несколько вкладок, разве это не один и тот же процесс? Если так, то убрать селективно («эту вкладку оставляем, а ту закрываем») не получится.

Comment: @VladD, я работаю по вебу сейчас в основном с Chrome, там точно каждая вкладка - отдельный процесс. По IE точно не скажу. Но я в одном из ответов обсуждал, не помню, может даже и с Вами, что главное в ответе - обозначить путь к решению :)